# How do I automatically update weekly, monthly and annual totals when entering daily total

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is my first time here so please forgive me if I did not find my answer prior to posting.

I have a spreadsheet that I use to keep track of my sales of an item. I keep track of this by day, week, month and year. I currently do the math in my head but would like to just enter a single number and have all the cells update. The cells would be:

- A1 = day
- A2 = week
- A3 = month
- A4 = year

Currently I enter my daily sales then add that "by hand" to the previous totals of the other columns so that each column has a total for its time frame.
The formula would basically be the same for cells A2, A3 and A4, and that is:

[Excel problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV4sg.jpg)

basically I want a formula to use 2 or 3 cells, cell1 would be just an entered value, (the day sales), cell 2 would be a formula that adds the contents of cell 1 to the current value of cell2 and then updates cell2 with the new value, in your head you would simply add the new value to the old value and write down the new value total, however excel doesn't seem to have a "hold" option like our memory so that is where the issue is coming.

I hope this example helps to clarify what I am looking to accomplish.

Now in my head this is very easy to accomplish however Excel refuses to do it easily.

I have been trying to find a solution however I do not even know how to pose the question other than as I just did, I have looked for tally, cycle counting, count ups, etc. however nothing gives me what I want.

It has been suggested that I use VBA, but I found no clear instructions for that either. I would be immensely appreciative if someone could help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi David, If you would kindly update you question with a small example of input data and desired output results, we may be able to help.

Comment: while I do appreciate when some one can clean up my poor grammar, and I do admit some of it does follow the line of inquiry I started, some does not or was not needed, also I do not appreciate it being done without asking first or presenting the reason for the modification, to me the title now implies a solution not a problem, the cell reference did not need to be bulleted, and could have been left as stated, some of the corrections are semantics such as changing from their to it's, or from VB to VBA, either is and would be correct. and I placed a Thank you at the end,

Comment: what is the reason for removing this? am I not allowed to express gratitude in advance of a solution?

Comment: Gary's Student, in answer to your question, I will try to word it in a way so as not to offend Mr. Blackwood's English sensibilities,  the cell "A1" will technically be the only cell that will have a changing total, this will add individually to the other cells, "Monday" sold 2 items, other cells will add 2 to their current totals, from 0 week total would now be 2, "Tuesday" sold 3, week total would now be 4, and so on.

Comment: BTW, since I am new, I can't seem to figure out how to use a full editor in here and keep having to edit because I hit enter for a line break, is there a way to do so?

Comment: How often do you "reset" the weekly, monthly and yearly totals?  Once per category (IE: the weekly total is for the current week or for the last 7 days, the monthly total for the current month, or last (365.25/12) days,  and the yearly for the current year or the last 365.25 days?

Comment: Hi David, your example is not clear, at least to me. I think the problem is not so complicated as it is for us to know how is your data organized in the excel sheet. Do you mind adding a screenshot of exactly how you plan to enter details specifically of the daily sales in an excel sheet. Afterall a picture is worth thousand words and the great minds on this forum will take minutes once they can "see" what you have in your mind/excel ;-) Good luck! ( I do not think there are any line breaks in comments)

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with only worksheet functions.

You will need to use VBA for the way you describe what is required, which is too complicated for anyone to help you out from scratch.

Frankly put, we will not do your work for you.

That being said, you can accomplish this by setting up a second sheet to track your daily progress.

[image: Sheet 2]]

Then use your first sheet to just link in and update your progress like the below example.

[image: Sheet 1]

**Formulas**

In A1 use `=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:B, TODAY(),Sheet2!B:B)` which will return your results for the current day.

In A2 use `=SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())-6),Sheet2!A:A,"<="&TODAY())` which will return your results for the previous 6 days including today.

In A3 use `=SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),Sheet2!A:A,"<="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,0))` will return results for the current month.

Comment: frankly put, I am not asking any one to do my work for me, I have a problem I do not know how to solve, I am asking a community that may know how to solve it for direction, if you felt put off by this then I'm sorry you wasted your time to respond, as for your "solution" it is far more complex than I want, all I need is a way to add a changing value from cell 1 to an existing value in cell 2 and update cell 2 with the new value, as stated a very simple think to do in your head, but for excel it seems to be next to impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description, you are keeping a running total.  However, I don't think you have accounted for the date-math that you are also doing in your head.

With a little re-organization of the problem you will make things much easier for yourself.  Then you can use *Pivot Tables* to slice and dice your data into interesting charts and/or tables containing subsets of your data.

I'll walk you through those two high-level topics below.

*Note: I don't have a Windows machine handy at the moment, so I will be using Google Sheets in the images and links I share.  Everything I discuss is supported by both Google Sheets and Excel and there is a common terminology across the applications.*

## Create a Data Table

When you start with a table of raw data, you simplify your requirements (no more math in your head) and leave your options open for various analytical approaches in the future.

Based on your example, each row in your data table will have two critical pieces of information.  The *date* and the *daily sales*.  Do not combine the sales numbers with the previous day.  One row represents one day and is independent of the adjacent rows' data.

In addition to the required data, the date and the sales, [I derived/decomposed several other values that will make slicing and dicing the data easier for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUCxt.png)

The derived data is all computed using simple formulas.  Notice the simplicity of the formula used to populate each column.  They are easy to understand and thus *good*.  You will appreciate the value of this when you are going back over code you wrote months ago trying to figure out what you were doing.

## Create a Pivot Table

Are you already familiar with *Pivot Tables*?  Click the upper left corner of your data table and select *Pivot Table* from the menu.  By default this will create a new sheet in your workbook.

[At first you will get an empty pivot table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eURfE.png)  You populate the table by selecting cross sections of rows and columns from your data.  For example, the [average sale per month table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eRfw.png)

Here is the [average sales per-year per-weekend day (Friday - Sunday)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIhDW.png).

You can copy/comment my [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b75T-Ozq213ENfy9v04K6n-pmiW9b__9DMW18TrllQ8/edit?usp=sharing), if you like, and do some experimenting of your own.

### Did that Help?

If there is an aspect that I didn't cover to your satisfaction or if you just have more questions, please let me know and I'll do what I can to help.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond, however the date is irrelevant to the problem, as I just edited above, (wish I could figure out how to do an actual response like my first question), cell1 would just be an entered value, cell2 would be the new value from cell1 added to the current value of cell2, as stated in your head it is very basic math = B=A+B(old)

Comment: > cell2 would be the new value from cell1 added to the current value of cell2
That is not possible, @David44010. A cell can hold **a value** or **a formula**, but not both at the same time.

Start by making a column of numerical values, say A1 through A10.  Next, select cell B1 and type **"=A1(return)"**. Literally.  You have to start with the "=" to create a formula in a cell. Then, select cell B2 and type **"=B1+A2(return)"**. Copy that formula by selecting cell B2 again, Ctrl-c, select B3, and Ctrl-v.  Notice that B3 contains the formula "=B2 + A3".